# phantomjs post request with formurlencoded

Tags: javascript, post, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs and I wrote a snippet of code that lets me make a post request with header and body. However when I make the post request the data does not get sent. What is the problem?

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
console.log('1');
var settings = {
  operation: "POST",
  encoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
      "Cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=ajq11hy45hmdmr51ra3ivtee; otohitsforgery=G6ZHZo_p9dC1oczq_GB8_9I76pgnmBoVbCpkKnG8oAJJLaEXhTlAJmsCT6Ttg5J_I4ajeODlp1OgksJ7xn1ZDTXLk85cr2vOxJ3kl5YsuCgmprP3WRNzm_f5wOJqgQNXLXwwdeBaxWqYeGi6PeQgbg2",
      "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  data: {
    "__RequestVerificationToken":"Ujol0sctq8I5bko4eLieDLP6ZiX1wShq3zP77JLpj8rAJy0MJIaI9JAt-ZfYmmqQkiL9QVUw7la6lqlwByqcUifU264H35Dq0pZUokl87jc5f1SpNA4G1_y5sF2eWB-MKWDC5WW33GdZnyRRXZP2ndGcBFB0hTwk5SPhGc3-z1I1",
      "ReturnUrl":"",
      "Email":"111111@gmail.com",
      "Password":"111111"

  }
};
page.open('url', settings, function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
   var cookies = page.cookies;

  console.log('Listing cookies:');
  for(var i in cookies) {
    console.log(cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
  }
  var content = page.content;
  console.log('Content: ' + content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Here is a screenshot when I track the request with fiddler I get the following. In my header everything is there:
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm4qv.png)

However in the webform I get nothing:[Webform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvBxX.png)

And then I get a 500 internal server error.

What do I need to change in order to make a post request so that the data is included in my post request?

I need the cookies also. I will not be able to login without the cookies. heres what I came up with your code snippet. But for some reason it is not working properly.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
console.log('1');

page.open("http://someurl.com",function(status){
 var cookies = page.cookies;
 console.log('Listing cookies:');
 for(var i in cookies) {
    console.log(cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
  }
cookies = cookies[1].name + '=' + cookies[1].value + '; ' + cookies[0].name + '=' + cookies[0].value;
console.log(cookies);
var settings = {
  operation: "POST",
  encoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
    "Cookie":cookies,
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  data: {
    "__RequestVerificationToken":"Ujol0sctq8I5bko4eLieDLP6ZiX1wShq3zP77JLpj8rAJy0MJIaI9JAt-ZfYmmqQkiL9QVUw7la6lqlwByqcUifU264H35Dq0pZUokl87jc5f1SpNA4G1_y5sF2eWB-MKWDC5WW33GdZnyRRXZP2ndGcBFB0hTwk5SPhGc3-z1I1",
    "ReturnUrl":"",
    "Email":"111111@gmail.com",
    "Password":"111111"

  }
var postBody = "";

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) { 
    postBody += (key + "=" + data[key] + "&");
});

console.log(postBody);
};
page.open('http://www.someurl.com', 'POST', settings, function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

How can I make this work?

```
});
```

Comment: Is `500 internal server error` happening when you make POST request?

Comment: Yes it is only happening when i make thé post request...its probably because thé cookie is Not correct but my main concern is how can i pass the content as formurlencoded

Comment: I think you should first investigate the 500 error and sort it out. See what's wrong in logs. Also, I don't think you're POSTing the right way, see [post.js example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js). To set custom headers, see [this page](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html)

Comment: this is the correct way look at this link: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html and for the 500 I know why I get this error. The cookies are incorrect and the token is incorrect. But as mentionned before my main concern is to pass the data. I just need a way to post the data and see the data in fiddler.

Comment: I concur, your code is valid, but it seems this way PhantomJS won't send data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code sample and it indeed won't work (PhantomJS 2.1.1).

However falling back to [the old way](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html#post-data-to-googlecom-and-report-success-or-fail) does send data:

```
var data = {
    "__RequestVerificationToken":"Ujol0sctq8I5bko4eLieDLP6ZiX1wShq3zP77JLpj8rAJy0MJIaI9JAt-ZfYmmqQkiL9QVUw7la6lqlwByqcUifU264H35Dq0pZUokl87jc5f1SpNA4G1_y5sF2eWB-MKWDC5WW33GdZnyRRXZP2ndGcBFB0hTwk5SPhGc3-z1I1",
    "ReturnUrl":"",
    "Email":"111111@gmail.com",
    "Password":"111111"
}

var postBody = "";

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) { 
    postBody += (key + "=" + data[key] + "&");
});

console.log(postBody);

page.open('http://example.com/', 'POST', postBody, function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

The server receives data:

```
array(4) {
  ["__RequestVerificationToken"]=>
  string(172) "Ujol0sctq8I5bko4eLieDLP6ZiX1wShq3zP77JLpj8rAJy0MJIaI9JAt-ZfYmmqQkiL9QVUw7la6lqlwByqcUifU264H35Dq0pZUokl87jc5f1SpNA4G1_y5sF2eWB-MKWDC5WW33GdZnyRRXZP2ndGcBFB0hTwk5SPhGc3-z1I1"
  ["ReturnUrl"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Email"]=>
  string(16) "111111@gmail.com"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(6) "111111"
}
```

**Edit 1**

> I need the cookies also. I will not be able to login without the cookies.

PhantomJS is able to process cookies automatically if you launch it with command switch --cookies-file:

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs --cookies-file=/home/usr/cookies.txt /home/usr/script.js
```

Comment: I need the cookies also. I will not be able to login without the cookies. here what I came up. But for some reason it is not working properly.

Comment: I edited my question could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Do you recieve cookies from outside or do you just need to support cookies in PhantomJS?

Comment: I receive the cookies through the first get request then when I make the post request I reuse that same cookie.

Comment: See Edit 1 in the answer

Comment: The cookies change everytime I make a new get request. The way you are proposing forces me to code something that will store the cookies in the cookie.txt file when I make the get request and then make the post request. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: I don't follow. Do you have GET and POST in different scripts? You can reuse cookies-file between script runs. You don't have to code cookie storage, PhantomJS manages it.

Comment: Everytime I run this script I make a get request first. This is to get the cookies so that when I make the post request I can use that cookie to login. Basically what you are saying is that if I use what you propose it will use the cookies that I get through my get and then uses it when I make my post request?

Comment: One last question. How can I get the value of an input type?
body > div.content > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.span6 > form > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(1) 

this is where the value is but how can I get it?

Comment: This is what it looks like:

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="OhG2aIRUXlWOZ4XlP89Uc21p8gv3N2V5laChqwYox086XfypjTyXK-cAGKpJCPO1Cb83lC_0ju2yAzXYoOasFyBDP6wMN82K5WRcOKguTTYKAI_rvedwhedWtXjixiq4h8IhKqZrczyQvUdKzWYe5tarAXu-gejJhs1gF0mCcZo1">` How can I get the value of it?

Comment: It it's working and the answer was useful, you could mark it as solved and vote. As for the input, I see you've already created another qeustion, right? :)

Comment: how do I mark it as the accepted answer? Just by upvoting your answer?
Yes I made a new post thank you.

Comment: I think clicking checkmark below up/down arrows does it. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/316193)